# What are the differences in taxes rules for specialty ETFs such as GLD (Gold ETF) and general ETFs?

Tags: united-states, taxes, etf, gold, capital-gain

I am in the 15% tax bracket. In terms of short term  hold and long term hold, I want to know what the differences in taxes rules for specialty ETFs such as GLD (Gold ETF) and general ETFs as are?

Comment: Why do you think there are differences?

Comment: @littleadv - because Congress has declared "nothing shall be easy."

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer is it only for GLD?

Comment: I know it's for the metal ETFs. Offhand, I'd say it might cover non-metal commodities, but not researched that. Remarkable what congress hath wrought. And why the pros cannot keep up.

Answer (score 9):

Gold ETFs are treated different than stock ETFs, as a collectable. This makes long-term investing in gold ETFs (for one year or longer) subject to a relatively large capital gains tax (maximum rate of 28%, rather than the 20% maximum rate that is applicable to most other long-term capital gains).

Read the Investopedia article [The Gold Showdown: ETFs Vs. Futures](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/exchangetradedfunds/08/gold-etf-gold-futures-showdown.asp#ixzz1ySoivZ00) for more details.